# appId set, but please call setLaunchOptions(launchOptions) to complete OneSignal init! in Capacitor

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, onesignal, capacitor

I'm developing push notifications in an Ionic app, my issue is that I can't see the users in OneSignal and send notifications. The only log that I have in xCode console is:

```
appId set, but please call setLaunchOptions(launchOptions) to complete OneSignal init!
```

This is my info:

```
Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.16
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 5.7.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 12.0.5
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 12.0.5
   @angular/cli                  : 12.0.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 4.0.0

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 3.1.1
   @capacitor/core : 3.2.2

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 6.2.0
   Cordova Platforms : none
   Cordova Plugins   : no whitelisted plugins (1 plugins total)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.15.3
   native-run  : 1.4.1

System:

   ios-sim : ios-sim/9.0.0 darwin-x64 node-v12.18.4
   NodeJS  : v12.18.4 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm     : 6.14.8
   OS      : macOS Big Sur
   Xcode   : Xcode 12.5.1 Build version 12E507
```

In android I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Seeing the same issue.

Comment: @JamesParker my advice is try to downgrade the version of OneSignal. I tried it and it works.

Comment: Are you using capacitor version 3? I’ve been running on version 3 of one signal without any issues until I updated to capacitor 3 which requires iOS 12.

Answer (score 3):

**This warning is informative and does not affect the plugin functionality.**

You can find the code that generates this warning in `OneSignal.m` file of the OneSignal iOS framework that Plugin depends on. It happens either when the `appId` is [set repeatedly](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/blob/fd06483b314f842c16e0a6f74dfb27a04dc7df66/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Source/OneSignal.m#L632) or when the `appId` is being set, but [`launchOptions` object has not yet been initialized](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-iOS-SDK/blob/fd06483b314f842c16e0a6f74dfb27a04dc7df66/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Source/OneSignal.m#L644).

If you look at the Plugin source files and the initialization function, you will see that [it does call](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK/blob/5372e152c5057c30f65bd3506f07995b50214015/src/ios/OneSignalPush.m#L99-L102) `setLaunchOptions(launchOptions)` after setting `appId`:

```objc
    NSString* appIdStr = (appId ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String: appId] : nil);
    [OneSignal setMSDKType:@"cordova"];
    [OneSignal setAppId:appIdStr];
    [OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

The code above triggers the warning at `[OneSignal setAppId:appIdStr]` but then immediately addresses it with `[OneSignal initWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions]` (which is the Objective-C function underlying the `setLaunchOptions(launchOptions)` Swift interface).